# Crop a raster by a list of sfc_polygons

Tags: list, buffer, polygon, crop, r-sf

I want to crop a land use raster by 16 polygons, which are 2km-buffers around agricultural fields.
My usual way of dealing with this (crop and mask, see code below) did not work, as my polygons are a list of sfc_Polygons.

I first use st_centroid and st_buffer to build buffers around the centroids of the fields.
The buffer-object is a list of 16 sfc_POLYGONS.
The land use object is a raster of 10*10m resolution.

```
fields$centroid <- st_centroid(fields$geometry)
buffer <- st_buffer(fields$centroid, 2000)
class(buffer) # [1] "sfc_POLYGON" "sfc"

buffer_landuse <- crop(land_use, buffer) # Error in .local(x, y, ...) : Cannot get an Extent object from argument y
buffer_landuse <- mask(buffer_landuse, buffer)
```

I guess I need to convert the list of sfc_POLYGONS into individual shapefiles to use the crop and mask functions. But I did not find a solutions so far. I would be happy about any help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: In case `crop()` and `rast()` are `{terra}` functions, try using `buffer <- st_buffer(fields$centroid, 2000) |> terra::vect()` instead. And it would be nice if you managed to make your example fully reproducible for others (libraries, data, ...).

Comment: Thanks for your help! I used the suggested terra::vect() function. Here is the full code including libraries:

```library(sf)
library(raster)
library(terra)
fields$centroid <- st_centroid(fields$geometry)` # Simple feature collection, Geometry type: POLYGON
buffer <- st_buffer(fields$centroid, 1000) |> terra::vect()
land_use_terra <- rast(land_use)
buff <- list("numeric", 16)
for (i in 1:dim(fields)[1]){
  buff[[i]] <- crop(land_use_terra, buffer[i])
  buff[[i]] <- mask(buff[[i]], buffer[i])
}
plot(buff[[1]])```

Comment: Did it work? Unfortunately, without the objects `fields` and `land_use` available, this can't be reproduced. Also, better include the code in the question by editing, not in one of the comments below. Btw, `list("numeric", 16)` creates a list with two objects: `"numeric"` of type character and `16` of type numeric. This does not initialize a list of length 16 and type numeric as probably intended.